# JVCL Tabbed Docking: No Close Button on Tabs

Tags: delphi, docking, jvcl

I am using the jvDocking components and have been unable to figure out how to enable close buttons on the tabs of forms that have been docked together as a set of tabs. I have tried various combinations of options such as:

```
tJVDoclient.EnableCloseButton := True;
```

And

```
tjvDockVSnetStyle.TabServeroption.ShowClosebuttonOnTabs := True;
tjvDockVSnetStyle.TabServeroption.ShowClosebuttonOnGrabber := False;
```

I am using Delphi XE2 Update 4.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I can't seem to get the close button to appear on tabs?

Thank you!

Comment: It depends what docking style you used, and what properties the docking style object has.    Your code suggests you are using the VSnet style. What is your actual active docking style? Look in the demo folder and you should see that there are jvDocking demos that show how to do this.

Comment: @Warren, I looked through the demos before asking my question and could not find anything that shows this feature working. Yes, I am working with VSNet style. Can you point me to which demo shows this? Is the explanation in the source of one of the demos? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be shown with CERTAIN docking styles, if you set the `ShowCloseButtonOnTabs` property to true. It's inside the `TabServerOption` section of the Dock Style Component (ie `TJvDockVIDStyle`).

I just tried it though, and it's possible there is a bug in this component as it does not work any more.

Comment: yes I am aware of the ShowCloseButtonOnTabs property and had experimented with it as mentioned in my OP. Thank you for confirming that it appears to be broken.

Comment: I suggest you file the bug here: http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/my_view_page.php

Comment: @WarrenP I have been checking this and went through the styles, but it seems, that the ShowClosebuttonOnTabs property is being only updated, but never used anywhere. Could it be, that the feature has been removed altogether? I am working with it, and managed to put together a solod application base (no unexpected error messages), but the close button is really missing. Simple scenario: 2 forms, one with docking server and a docking style (VSNet) and the second with dock client. Set the properties to show close buttons, and presto, no close buttons.

Comment: That property only works in some of the docking styles. Most of the styles ignore it. The original authors would know why.